# 'property' object is not iterable trying to get response after calling the API being used

Tags: python, api, dictionary, request, fastapi

I have this error when I am trying to get response after the call of the API I want to use.

```
ValueError: [TypeError("'property' object is not iterable"), 
  TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

I am trying to use fastapi in order  get from the client the latitudes and longitudes so i could show the public trasnportation of that area. I could do this with an API called GeoApify. However, I have a problem and I can not find my error.

I make a request by using a dictionary in order to put all the parameters for my filter and then I convert the response to JSON. But i have this error.

```
 from pickletools import string1
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    import requests
    from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
    
    app = FastAPI()
    
    
    @app.get("/thanos/{lon}/{lat}")
    async def read_item(lat : float,lon : float):
        url = "https://api.geoapify.com/v2/places"
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    
        dict = {
            "categories" :   'public_transport',
            "filter"     :   'circle:' + str(lon) + ',' + str(lat) + ",500",
            "limit"      :   '20',
            "apiKey"     :   '086a77f34e3a4ed583da9606318ca0ac'
         }
    
    
        params = dict
        headers = CaseInsensitiveDict(params)
            
        headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
    
        resp = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    
        # resp = requests.get(url = url, params = params)
        data = resp.json
        return resp
```

Comment: unrelated: with FastAPI (async) use HTTPX (async), not Requests (sync)

Comment: Can you add where that error happens exactly? Also, as a suggestion, don't use dict as a variable, it is a built-in class in python that you overwrite locally.

Answer (score 2):

Use as below:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
import urllib

app = FastAPI()

url = "https://api.geoapify.com/v2/places"

@app.get("/{lon}/{lat}")
def read_item(lat : float, lon : float):
    params = {
       "categories" :   'public_transport',
       "filter"     :   'circle:' + str(lon) + ',' + str(lat) + ",500",
       "limit"      :   '20',
       "apiKey"     :   '086a77f34e3a4ed583da9606318ca0ac'
    }

    headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
    
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params, headers=headers)
    
    return resp.json()
```